# Deserializing Array List created on PC in Android App

Tags: java, android, serialization

I wrote a java program on my PC which serializes an ArrayList to file. The array list contains objects of a custom class. I would like to deserialize that ArrayList in an Android application. However, when I attempt to do so a system error is returned reading:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: (package name on pc)$(class name)
```

The name of the class, the implementation, and its serialVersionUID are the same on both the PC and Android, however the package name differs between the two. Is there a way to get the pc generated file to load? I can change the serialization code as needed.

Comment: How complex is the object? Depending on what it is I might suggest using JSON, or XML to store the object as text instead of Serializable interface. Which would presumably solve the issue that you are having.

Comment: The objects store references to one another, so a text based storage system seems tricky.

Comment: Am I correct to assume that you have double checked that the class / implementation / serialVersionUID are the same for all of the object types? and not just the top level one.

Comment: I have -- before I had the class being serialized implemented as a static subclass, just changed it to its own file and retried. Still get the same error.